# stripslashes in Android

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I had a issue in wordpress.

```
$wpdb->insert('table', 
          array("report_name" => $_REQUEST['report_name']), array('%s'));
```

Input of report_name is **O'nion**

It insert it into database as **O\'nion**

In my api, I fetch the values from database and encode as json

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT report_id, report_name FROM report WHERE 1", "ARRAY_A" );
if( $result )
  echo json_encode( $result );
else
  echo json_encode( array() );
```

The api is called in android and it display in listview.
I want to stripslashes in report_name. Now it display as O\'nion and i want as O'nion in Android

Note: In web side, i used stripslashes() function to solve above issue. But I don't know how do it in Android.

**Edit:**

Is any solution for stripslashes the array value in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue in PHP side

I use `array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $value )`

In wordpress has `stripslashes_deep()` to achieve this

```
echo json_encode( stripslashes_deep( $result ) );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sanitization method to do this task. I don't know if you're handling more escaped characters, but an example would be this:

```
report_name = report_name.replaceAll("\\'", "\'");
```

Comment: Nice. But I want all escape characters solution.

Comment: You can either specify one by one (they're not as many) or simply use `replaceAll("\\", "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.replace() function. Try this,

```
String replacedStr = stringname.replace("\\", "");
```

Hope this helps you.